# Private key of a specific bitcoin address

Tags: blockchain

I need to find out the private key of a specific bitcoin address **'1FVoAyGnHueH1uNR4dAQgRZcsBkAd3Mo3K'**. This is the bitcoin address of a scammer who made me lose my last savings in the name of cryptocurrency trading. I recovered the fund with the help of a special intelligence unit but it is still 'Non-spendable'. Please help me recover my funds and save my life.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot.  If you could, the cryptography on which Bitcoin relies would be worthless.

I don't know who this "special intelligence unit" is, but if all they did was find the address, then that is no help.  (If the "intelligence unit" took money from you to find out this address, and told you that they had recovered your funds, then you've been scammed again.)

You have not recovered your funds and you are not going to.  Your time will be better spent figuring out how to do without them.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this could (theoretically, with almost 0 probability of success) be done:

1. Go forward by generating new private keys until you find one that corresponds to this address. There are about 2^256 possible private keys (actually a smaller number, but it's huge).
2. Go backwards by breaking all the cryptography involved in Bitcoin:

First, that address is the hash **9f03f344848612f1f456b08187706017888a6bb6**. This is in form hash160, which is `RIPEMD-160 (SHA-256 (Public Key))`.

Step 1: Break RIPEMD-160 to get the SHA-256 hash.

Step 2: Break SHA-256 to get the public key.

(You could also get this public key once it's published when that key is used to spend. Of course, at that point it may not help you.)

Step 3: Break secp256k1, Bitcoin's elliptic curve, to get the private key from the public key.

Good luck spending less in research costs than the $4,500 you hope to get back. (Plus if you somehow succeed, consider the greater impact on Bitcoin.)

3. Determine who owns the address and get the private key from them.